# C# WPF put a video player in its own thread when not in its own window

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, video

I have a C# WPF application that can open a few synchronised videos in separate windows using MediaElements in Windows.

I was having some performance issues (frame rate) when I had a few videos running all on the same UI thread so I had a go at putting each window in its own thread with its own dispatcher

```
    public void ShowVideoWindow(string source)
    {
        if (!_videoWindows.ContainsKey(source))
        {
            Thread videoThread = new Thread(delegate ()
            {
                VideoWindow videoWindow = new VideoWindow(source);
                videoWindow.Closed += VideoWindow_Closed;
                videoWindow.Show();

                _videoWindows[source] = videoWindow;

                System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
            });

            videoThread.IsBackground = true;
            videoThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); // needs to be STA or throws exception
            videoThread.Name = source + " - video";
            videoThread.Start();
        }
    }
```

This works really well. Each video window runs nicely and I just have to be careful that I only access the other windows through invoking calls to the correct dispatcher.

The issue is that I don't want these windows to be completely separate. I would like to use dockable windows as part of AvalonDock. Is there a way for me to get just the video control to run in a separate thread? Should I be using something more advanced than MediaElement? I am only using it because it was easy to get going with.